# IDEA(AndroidStudio)-Git->Show History: Chinese encoding error

Tags: intellij-idea

Please all developers help me for this: When opened "Git->Show History" and shown log list, there will be some encoding exception if commit-message contains Chinese info. How can I resolve this?
[image]

Comment: This question seems to be about either intellj-idea or android-studio, not Git. I picked one of the two and changed the tag, but if I picked the wrong one, please change the tag again.

Answer (score 0):

Good luck for myself. And I've resolved this, in details:

```
1. Settings -> Apperance & Behavior  -> Apperance：open checkbox 『Use custom size: .AppleSystemUIFont』
2. after opened checkbox, you can choose another font instead of default given by intelij IDE. On my macOS-AndroidStudio/IDEA, directly using the first recommended ".AppleSystemUIFont" already display Chinese log infomation. Of course, you can choose other Fonts to test as long as IDE displays normally.
```

That's all.